# Laravel on EC2 trying to connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel, pdo, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a Laravel installed on Amazon's EC2 with a separate database on Amazon's RDS and I can't connect to the RDS through changing the mysql details in Laravel's database.php file. I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '******.*******.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (13)
```

RDS is not using Multi AZ and the zone of RDS is in the same zone as EC2 (us-west-2a).

Security groups of the RDS is not available and it takes me to the EC2 security groups.
I have the MySQL port 3306 open in my inbound rules and have all traffic open on my outbound rules.

On the EC2 server, I do have PDO installed and is being picked up on phpinfo();

The strangest thing is, I can access the RDS through the terminal and from my desktop using a 3rd party software ( HeidiSQL )

Any ideas what to try in order for Laravel to connect to Amazon's RDS ?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you mentioned you are on the zone us-west-2a but your error says us-west-2

Comment: Nope, instance endpoint is 100% correct.

Comment: Which database.php file are you using? Do you have one setup for your current environment? (config/local/database.php vs config/database.php)

Comment: I'm using: '/app/config/database.php'. It is definitely using that configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I got hold of Amazon support and after a few minutes decided to recreate a new instance of EC2.

Was using RHEL and changed to AMI.

Everything works fine now.